# compare list of lists and create clusters

Tags: python, list

I have a list that has 10,000 lists of strings of different lengths. For this question, I will make it simple and give an example of only a list that has 10 lists as follows.

```py
list = [['a','w','r', 't'], ['e','r', 't', 't', 'r', 'd', 's'], ['a','w','r', 't'], ['n', 'g', 'd', 'e', 's'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['t', 'f', 'h', 'd', 'p'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a','w','r', 't'], ['s','c','d'], ['e','r', 't', 't', 'r', 'd', 's']]
```

what I want is to compare each list with all other lists and group the similar lists into one new list (called a cluster) and also group the list indices.

**Expected output:**

```py
cluster_1_lists = [['a','w','r', 't'], ['a','w','r', 't'], ['a','w','r', 't']]

cluster_1_indices = [0,2,7]

cluster_2_lists = [['e','r', 't', 't', 'r', 'd', 's'],['e','r', 't', 't', 'r', 'd', 's']]

cluster_2_indices = [1,9]

cluster_3_lists = [['n', 'g', 'd', 'e', 's']]

cluster_3_indices = [3]

cluster_4_lists = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]

cluster_4_indices = [4,6]

cluster_5_lists = [['t', 'f', 'h', 'd', 'p']]

cluster_5_indices = [5]

cluster_6_lists = [['s','c','d']]

cluster_6_indices = [8]
```

Can you help me to implement this in python?

Comment: *group the similar lists* -- define similarity?

Comment: similar lists are those must-have same items, # of items, and order of items. if any list loses even one condition of the three, then it will be a different list.

Comment: i'd rather call it **same** lists then.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here, I'll basically be using a dictionary to make a cluster. Here's what I've done:

```
list= [['a','w','r', 't'], ['e','r', 't', 't', 'r', 'd', 's'], ['a','w','r', 't'], ['n', 'g', 'd', 'e', 's'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['t', 'f', 'h', 'd', 'p'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a','w','r', 't'], ['s','c','d'], ['e','r', 't', 't', 'r', 'd', 's']]
cluster = {}

for i in list:
    cluster[''.join(i)] = []
    cluster[''.join(i)+'_indices'] = []
for j in range(len(list)-1):
    for k in cluster:
        if ''.join(list[j]) == k:
            cluster[k].append(list[j])
            cluster[k+'_indices'].append(j)
print(cluster)
```

The first for loop basically creates a key with the joint name of your list, because you cannot have a key as a list. Then, it stores it val as an empty list which will further be appended. In the second for loop, it iterates again through the list and inside it I have iterated through the keys in the cluster (dict). Then, it basically checks if the joint list is equal to the key name, if yes it appends the value. The output will look like this:

```
Output: {'awrt': [['a', 'w', 'r', 't'], ['a', 'w', 'r', 't'], ['a', 'w', 'r', 't']], 'awrt_indices': [0, 2, 7], 'erttrds': [['e', 'r', 't', 't', 'r', 'd', 's']], 'erttrds_indices': [1], 'ngdes': [['n', 'g', 'd', 'e', 's']], 'ngdes_indices': [3], 'abc': [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']], 'abc_indices': [4, 6], 'tfhdp': [['t', 'f', 'h', 'd', 'p']], 'tfhdp_indices': [5], 'scd': [['s', 'c', 'd']], 'scd_indices': [8]}
```

*Note: Creating separate variables as you want will just make the code messy, python has a solution to it which is dictionaries and thus I've used it.*

Comment: I've made a change in the code as I didn't see that you want the indices as well. I've done the required changes and it should work well now!

Comment: Whats the point of using a dict but treating it like a list?

Comment: @Mohsen Ali want's it to be stored in every customized variable which is practically not a good idea as they mentioned their data. Thus, they want the value as a list if you look at their desired output and I've stored it in a dictionary with their values.

Comment: I mean why do you do a linear search for the key? Just do `k = ''.join(list[j])`

Comment: Making clusters as a dictionary is not good for me since the list items actually are words or sentences (I just gave letters here to show the example). The dictionary keys will be very long in your scenario.

Comment: @MohsenAli And the problem with that is what?

Comment: the problem is coming after that when I would call each cluster for further processing. can we change the keys to integers like this?

Output: {'0': [['a', 'w', 'r', 't'], ['a', 'w', 'r', 't'], ['a', 'w', 'r', 't']], '0_indices': [0, 2, 7], '1': [['e', 'r', 't', 't', 'r', 'd', 's']], '1_indices': [1], '2': [['n', 'g', 'd', 'e', 's']], '2_indices': [3], '3': [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']], '3_indices': [4, 6], '4': [['t', 'f', 'h', 'd', 'p']], '4_indices': [5], '5': [['s', 'c', 'd']], '5_indices': [8]}

Comment: You can do it, I just gave you an idea with the list you provided.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the working answer:

```
for i in list:
cluster[''.join(i)] = []
xx = []
xx_idx=[]
for k in cluster:
   yy = []
   yy_ixd = []
   for j in range(len(list)):
      if k == ''.join(list[j]):
         yy.append(list[j])
         yy_ixd.append(j)
   xx.append(yy)
   xx_idx.append(yy_ixd)
print("output", xx)
print("indices: ", xx_idx)
```

**Output:**

output [[['a', 'w', 'r', 't'], ['a', 'w', 'r', 't'], ['a', 'w', 'r', 't']], [['e', 'r', 't', 't', 'r', 'd', 's'], ['e', 'r', 't', 't', 'r', 'd', 's']], [['n', 'g', 'd', 'e', 's']], [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']], [['t', 'f', 'h', 'd', 'p']], [['s', 'c', 'd']]]

indices:  [[0, 2, 7], [1, 9], [3], [4, 6], [5], [8]]